# How to get socket state in solaris 10?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, solaris, getsockopt

How to get socket state in solaris 10?

In solaris 8 , there used to be SO_STATE macro in socket.h , and we were able to use it as below:

```
getsockopt(skt, SOL_SOCKET, SO_STATE, (char *)&sockbufsize, &size);
```

But, there is no such macro supported in solaris 10. So, how to do it in solaris 10?

Comment: are you sure you want SO_STATE?  It seems you might awaken an ancient evil by touching that.

Comment: yes i want to use SO_STATE , but it seems like there is no way , and no alternative present in solaris 10 to use this option.

Comment: what does SO_STATE even do, or rather used to do?

Comment: SO_STATE return a integer value where each bit ( in integer value) have different meaning , so if sockbufsize is 32 , it mean 5th bit is set , and it represent "connection indication for poll" I think.

Comment: It's been a very long time since it was removed. And you can not use it on Solaris 10 even if you just put the numeric value there - getsockopt will fail. Tell us why do you need it, and we will probably be able to tell you how to do this. XY problem, I belive.